# Receiving emails, processing them and saving them on the database of my web application

Tags: php, mysql

I need in some way to accept incoming emails to my web application and save them in the database. My web application is written in PHP language and im using MySQL database.

I have no idea how can i do that... I builded the rest of my web application by myself but this is very complicated for me.

For example i need to know how can i accept incoming emails first... and where? in which email address my web application will accept these emails...???

Then how i will get them from there? How i will process them and how i will store them in my database?

Please help me with an example, some piece of code, anything!
Any help is accepted.

Im not an expert so a piece of code will help me a lot.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What type of mail server are you running on what OS?

Comment: What's your end goal? Let's start there.

Comment: I do not have any email account connected on my web application. i dont know how i can connect one...  A final implementation should allow the users of my application to send emails to my web application and my web application should process them somehow and save them in the database. If someone tell me how i can accept emails first and how can i save them in my database i think i can do the rest. Thank you!

Comment: @user1216858 I don't understand WHY you're doing this. It's seems like your over complicating the matter. When you say you want to store the email in your database, what are you intending to do with the data later? Why not just set up a simple POP3 email account and send email to it. WHY does your application need to store the email?

Comment: My application acts as a huge storage application. This will allow the users to forward some important emails that contains information straight to the web application. Later on the users will be able to visit the application and have a look on all the information that are stored there! I dont know what is POP3 and how it works! Can this help me?

Answer (score 3):

You basically have two choices:

1. Run an SMTP program (such as Postfix or Sendmail) on your server to receive the emails, and use procmail to pass them to your code
2. get an email account on an external host service and retrieve the email using one of the POP3 client packages for PHP, such as [pop3class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2-PHP-Access-to-e-mail-mailboxes-using-the-POP3-protocol.html)

Option 1 is much harder to do, and you have to learn about administering an email server, which is not a trivial task.  Option 2 is relatively easy and is the one I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to setup a regular email address with some freemailer and then check this account.

A start for this might be the POP3-class of [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

Comment: He said incoming mail, not outgoing.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, having taken a closer look, you would have to edit the pop3 class, but it should provide a starting point. editing answer now ...

Comment: It says "POP Before SMTP Authentication Class" in the source.

Comment: For incoming mail please! i do not have any email address connected to my web application. How i can connect one and how can i accept emails there. Then how i get them and how i sace them in my database?